# Discord.js: Export Ban list command not working

Tags: discord, discord.js, command, export

I recently started working on discord ban bot with 3 main features:

1. Export IDs of all banned users in current Server/Guild.
2. Import IDs of banned users into current guild
3. Transfer ban list from current server to target server. (Under development)

None of the slash commands are working even though the logic is seemingly correct.

I'm following the discordjs guide & managed to make a Time Tag generator bot & this is my 2nd bot project. I admit I'm not familier with Javascript but the guide is very helpful nonetheless

Here is the export-ban-list code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token, pasteUser, pastePass, pasteKey } = require('../config.json');

const paste = require('better-pastebin');

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);
const date = new Date();
paste.setDevKey(pasteKey);
paste.login(pasteUser, pastePass);

function new_paste(serverName, results) {
    const outputFile = `${serverName}-${date}.txt`;
    paste.create({
        contents: results,
        name: outputFile,
        expires: '1D',
        anonymous: 'true',
    },
    function(success, data) {
        if (success) {
            return data;
        }
        else {
            return 'There was some unexpected error.';
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('export-ban-list')
        .setDescription('Exports ban list of current server'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const bans = await rest.get(
            Routes.guildBans(interaction.guildId),
        );
        await interaction.deferReply(`Found ${bans.length} bans. Exporting...`);
        console.log(`Found ${bans.length} bans. Exporting...`);

        let results = [];
        bans.forEach((v) => {
            results.push(v.user.id);
        });
        results = JSON.stringify(results);

        const fe = new_paste(interaction.serverName, results);
        return interaction.editReply(fe);

    },
};
```

This command basically calculates the number of users banned, makes an array & exports it to pastebin.
The issue is, the bot code reaches till calculation part, but when it comes to making the list, console throws me errors:

```
Found 13 bans. Exporting...
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:311:15)
    at async CommandInteraction.editReply (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:137:21)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\index.js:41:3) {
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/webhooks/897454611370213436/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246ODk4ODkyNzI0NTcxMzczNjA5OmtPeGtqelQ5eUFhMnNqVzc1Q3BpMWtQZUZRdVhveGQxaHFheFJCdVFoUWNxNUk5TVpGbThEQjdWcDdyaHZyaUJPeUpsRWFlbUp0WnVLYjB5V0RtYmJCSmlNU2wwUVlka1hYMHg0bHRJbzlHelVwRmJ6VUpRaXF2YktaVDN1ZlVp/messages/@original',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at CommandInteraction.reply (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:89:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Github\Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot\index.js:45:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

Comment: Try console logging the fe variable. It might be undefined or an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17011740/jim) I used the console.log() to check what was going on.

And indeed the `data` from function inside `new_paste()` wasn't being returned to `fe`.

(I had messed up the return scopes basically)

Here is the final code after fixes & scope resolutions

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token, pasteUser, pastePass, pasteKey } = require('../config.json');

const paste = require('better-pastebin');

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);
const date = new Date();

paste.setDevKey(pasteKey);
paste.login(pasteUser, pastePass);

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('export-ban-list')
        .setDescription('Exports ban list of current server'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const bans = await rest.get(
            Routes.guildBans(interaction.guildId),
        );
        await interaction.deferReply(`Found ${bans.length} bans. Exporting...`);
        console.log(`Found ${bans.length} bans. Exporting...`);

        let results = [];
        bans.forEach((v) => {
            results.push(v.user.id);
        });
        results = JSON.stringify(results);
        console.log(results);

        const outputFile = `${interaction.guild.name}-${date}.txt`;
        paste.create({
            contents: results,
            name: outputFile,
            expires: '1D',
            anonymous: 'true',
        },
        function(success, data) {
            if (success) {
                return interaction.editReply(data);
            }
            else {
                return interaction.editReply('There was some unexpected error.');
            }
        });
    },
};
```

And finally I get the proper pastebin url as output.
Code hosted [here](https://github.com/MRDGH2821/Discord-Ban-Utils-Bot/blob/main/commands/export-ban-list.js)

Answer (score 0):

I think your npm package better-pastebin has an error. I am not familiar with that npm package, so I can’t determine whether it has an error for you, but I think if you change the npm package, the error will not appear.